# List item is detached from ListView even they are supposed to be shown on screen (Android 7.0)

Tags: android, listview, android-7.0-nougat

**Device:**
Nexus 5X (Both emulator and real device)

**Android OS Version:**
API 24 (older API works fine)

**What I did:**
I override the ArrayAdapter getView() method to return List directly. (I do this on purpose. In real case, views with different design are returned)
When I run the app, it works fine at first.
After scrolling down to the bottom and return to the top, some of the item cannot be tapped.(There is a sample project down below)

**What I expect:**
I expect each row can be tapped no matter how I scroll.

**What I have investigated:**
I override the View's method to print log for onAttachedToWindow/ onDetachedFromWindow. And I have the following log.

---

// When I scroll to the bottom for the first time, it seems good.

```
    0 onAttachedToWindow
    1 onAttachedToWindow
    2 onAttachedToWindow
    3 onAttachedToWindow
    4 onAttachedToWindow
    5 onAttachedToWindow
    0 onDetachedFromWindow
    6 onAttachedToWindow
    1 onDetachedFromWindow
    7 onAttachedToWindow
    2 onDetachedFromWindow
    8 onAttachedToWindow
    3 onDetachedFromWindow
    9 onAttachedToWindow
    4 onDetachedFromWindow
    4 onAttachedToWindow
```

// When I scroll back to the top, it seems that something is wrong.

```
    9 onDetachedFromWindow
    3 onAttachedToWindow
    3 onDetachedFromWindow
    8 onDetachedFromWindow
    2 onAttachedToWindow
    2 onDetachedFromWindow
    7 onDetachedFromWindow
    1 onAttachedToWindow
    1 onDetachedFromWindow
    6 onDetachedFromWindow
    0 onAttachedToWindow
    0 onDetachedFromWindow
    5 onDetachedFromWindow
```

// items 3,2,1,0 detached after attaching, even though they are still on the screen.

---

To me, the way "onDetachedFromWindow" is called is wired.
And I have used "Android Device Monitor" to take a view hierarchy capture, which I found that the item cannot be tapped is missing in the view hierarchy. I am wondering if the items are detached unexpectedly during scrolling.

Please let me know if you know where the problem is.

**Sample Project:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmsPd8_SvZ6SVJnZHMzUmdjMHc/view?usp=sharing